# Angular Hybrid App Test "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null"

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-hybrid

I have a simple test:

```
it ('should be able to navigate to add program', fakeAsync(() => {
  let href = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.add-program-btn'));
  let link = href.nativeElement.getAttribute('href');
  expect(link).toEqual('/program/new');
}));
```

And keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
```

I've tried using `tick()` with like `20000`, and adding `fixture.detectChanges()` but nothing works. Another test that checks if a button was clicked and a function called has the same error. Is it that it can't find the element?

Everything this test is using is in Angular so I don't think it's because it's a hybrid app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `console.log(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.innerHTML)` to see what the HTML looks like.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems like the root of the problem is an `ngIf` that I have in the parent container. So now what should I do, set whatever the `ngIf` to true so that the correct HTML is in the DOM ?

Comment: However, now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

This happens when `*ngIf` is being used in the template and it's expression evaluates to a falsy value. You should set appropriate inputs to the component so that `*ngIf` can evaluate to true;

Here is some sample code:

```js
it ('should be able to navigate to add program', async(() => {
  const component = fixture.componentInstance;

  // Set particular input so that ngIf makes your href visible to true
  component.inputName = true;

  // run change detection, updated input value should get used
  fixture.detectChanges();

  // in some cases you may want for things to stabilize
  await fixture.whenStable();

  // For debugging prupose, you may want to log innerHTML
  console.log(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.innerHTML)

  // Rest of the test
  let href = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.add-program-btn'));
  let link = href.nativeElement.getAttribute('href');

  expect(link).toEqual('/program/new');
}));
```